# Why is my Tic-Tac-Toe game not starting even though my server and client are connecting and communicating properly?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, tic-tac-toe

The tic-tac-toe game is built using socket programming in Python. It consists of a server and a client, where the players can choose their symbols and start playing the game. The server is responsible for creating the board and handling the game's flow, while the client connects to the server and sends the player's moves to the server. The game logic is implemented in the play_game function, where each player's move is checked against the winning conditions to determine the winner or draw.

ttt.py

```
import socket

# server
def server(host, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen()
        print(f"Server listening at {host}, port {port}")

        while True:
            connection, addr = s.accept()
            print(f"Connected by {addr}")

            # Ask user which symbol they want to play with
            symbol = connection.recv(1024).decode()
            print(f"Player {addr} chose {symbol}")

            # Receive 'y_or_n' response from client
            y_or_n = connection.recv(1024).decode()
            print(f"Opponent's response: {y_or_n}")

            # Play the game with the chosen symbol
            if symbol == 'X':
                play_game('O', connection)
            else:
                play_game('X', connection)

# client
def client(host, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        print("Connected to server")

        # Send player symbol choice
        symbol_choice = input("Do you want to play as X or O? ")
        s.send(bytes(symbol_choice, 'utf-8'))

        # Wait for game to start
        start_game = input("Do you want to start the game? (Y/N)").upper()
        s.send(bytes(start_game, 'utf-8'))

        if start_game == 'Y':
            print("Game started!")
            play_game(symbol_choice, s)
        else:
            print("Game cancelled")
            s.close()

# play_game function
def play_game(player, connection):
    # Receive 'y_or_n' response from the server
    y_or_n = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

    if y_or_n == 'N':
        turn = player
    else:
        turn = other_player(player)

    print(turn)

    board = createboard()
    winner = ' '

    printboard(board)

    # loop condition: no winner and no draw
    while winner == ' ' and not isdraw(board):

        if turn != player:
            print("Waiting for opponent...")
            move = connection.recv(1024)
            if not move:
                print("Your opponent is forfeiting; closing game")
                connection.close()
                exit(0)
        else: # turn == player
            move = input("Your move: ")

        try:
            if player != turn:
                move = move.decode('utf-8')

            row, col = move[0:2]
            rowind = ord(row) - ord('A')
            colind = int(col) - 1

            board[rowind][colind] = turn
            printboard(board)

            if winningmove(rowind, colind, turn, board):
                winner = turn
            else:
                turn = other_player(turn)

            if winner != ' ':
                if winner == player:
                    print("Congratulations! You won!")
                    connection.send(bytes("Congratulations! You won!", 'utf-8'))
                else:
                    print("Sorry, you lost.")
                    connection.send(bytes("Sorry, you lost.", 'utf-8'))
                break

            elif isdraw(board):
                print("It's a draw!")
                connection.send(bytes("It's a draw!", 'utf-8'))
                break

            else:
                if player == turn:
                    move = input("Your move: ")
                else:
                    connection.send(bytes("Your turn now!", 'utf-8'))
```

The ttt_board is a separate module that I implemented which contains functions related to the Tic Tac Toe game board. It includes functions to create the board, print the board, check if the board is full, check if a player has won, and get the available moves on the board.

I used two terminals to run my code, one for the server and one for the client, by using the commands "python ttt.py -s" for the server and "python ttt.py -c" for the client. Although the print statements and prompts in both the client and server functions are working correctly, the play_game function is not executing as expected. I have tried to print the values of y_or_n and turn but I am not getting any output. Can someone please help me identify the issue with my logic?

Comment: The very first thing you or anyone should do is to do basic [debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html). Please do that first, and share the results; if you haven't even done your due diligence yet, it's not reasonable to expect us to do these basic steps.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and trim your code into a [mre]

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried printing the value of "y_or_n" and "turn" in the "play_game" function but I see no output.  Other than that, I see no errors or exceptions raised by the play_game function. I see no syntactical errors either.

Comment: By not stepping through the code with a debugger, you can't even be sure the code in that function is even running. If nothing is printed, then the print statements aren't being reached. As for why, only you can figure that out, via debugging; step trough the code line-by-line and see why it's skipping over the prints, and maybe even the whole function.

Comment: Both sides go into `play_game` and expect to receive something, but neither side has sent anything, so they are both waiting.

Comment: Also standard statement that TCP is not message-based.  `send('x')` and `send('y')` could be `recv(1024)` as `'xy'`.  It is a byte stream.  You should clearly define a protocol that defines what a complete message is, and buffer calls to recv until you have a complete message in the buffer.  It is also possible for `send` to not send all data, so check the return value or use `sendall`.